# CGAL: Transformation Matrix for Rotation given two lines/vectors/directions

Tags: geometry, rotation, cgal

How do I generate a transformation matrix for rotating points/others by the angle between two lines/vectors/directions in CGAL?

2D is what I need. 3D is what I love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.4/doc_html/cgal_manual/Kernel_23_ref/Class_Aff_transformation_2.html) you have these tools to work with:

> `Aff_transformation_2<Kernel> t ( const Rotation, Direction_2<Kernel> d, Kernel::RT num, Kernel::RT den = RT(1))`
>
> > approximates the rotation over the angle indicated by direction d, such that the differences between the sines and cosines of the rotation given by d and the approximating rotation are at most num/den each.
> >     Precondition:   num/den>0 and d != 0.
>
> `Aff_transformation_2<Kernel>     t.operator* ( s)`    composes two affine transformations.
>
> `Aff_transformation_2<Kernel>     t.inverse ()`   gives the inverse transformation.

With them you should be able to compute the matrices corresponding to the two directions and use an identity along the lines of:

```
Mat(d1-d2) === Mat(d1)*Inv(Mat(d2))
```

to get what you want.